# CryptObject | Fingerprint Recognition and Auth

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

Learning fingerprint recognition, I came across CryptoObject. Of course, there is a lot of information about it and I tried to google it, but anyway I don't understand what it exactly does.

So my question is: what it exactly does? Does it give permission to an application to use SecretKey in the KeyStore or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class is a wrapper (or container object) that is general. It's intended to be a container for more specific cryptographic primitives which are supported by `FingerprintManager`, i.e. Signature, Cipher and Message authentication objects.

This allows one to handle these objects with a single type.